# Android Wear 2.0 Complications Minimum Update Time

Tags: wear-os

According to the [Android Wear Developer Training guide for Wear 2.0 Watch Face Complications](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/complications.html), though the developer can, via the manifest file, define a set interval where a complication provider can request an update, there is the caveat that "update requests are not guaranteed to be sent with this frequency" and that "the system does apply a minimum update period, and in particular, update requests may come less often when the device is in ambient mode or is not worn."

Is there any documentation or source specifying exactly what this minimum update period is, or how it is derived?

**UPDATE**: The reason that I am asking this is that our organization is looking to develop an application that will both run on Apple Watch and Android Wear, and it was noted by the Apple Watch side of development that the Apple Watch OS only permits 50 updates to their complications for every 24 hour time period; the project manager for this application is very curious if the Android Wear 2.0 OS has any similar restrictions, or if a developer is, in theory, capable of updating complications "freely" (i.e. without consideration of the end user's device's battery).

Answer (score 1):

As I've read the documentation you linked, it didn't state the minimum update period you can specify. However, based from this [example](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/data-providers/blob/master/4-ranged-data/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), developers should consider intervals in the order of minutes. Also, remember that this is only a guidance for the system. Android Wear may update less frequently. Unfortunately, I cannot also see any documentation regarding the exact time to specify but this value should be set as large as possible, to not have a too big impact on the device battery, due to frequent updates. You can check this [blog](https://medium.com/@danybony_/wear-complications-api-16ab65290aa1#.gneteyxiu). But if your app needs to push updates instead of updating on a regular schedule, you should set this value to `0` and use `ProviderUpdateRequester.requestUpdate()` instead to trigger an update request when you need one.